# кража cookie злоумышленником

Tags: php, cookie

Как избежать входа по куки файлам, которые были украдены?
Был вариант 1) использовать fingerprint, но техника apple ломает всю идею. 2)записывать ip, но адрес у многих серый 3) использовать токены, но 1 токен нельзя использовать на нескольких устройствах.
Как решить проблему с безопасностью ?

Comment: почему нельзя раздать несколько токенов? И кто сказал, что токен нельзя украсть? Используйте OAuth2

Comment: токен будет постоянно разлогинивать 1 устройство, если зайти со 2. Токен тоже можно украсть, но его можно очень часто менять. OAuth2  можно использовать, но большинство пользователей на новых сайтах не используют свои аккаунты гугл итд для авторизации.

Comment: Проблема решается довольно банально - берите уникальные данные о пользователе аля айпи,  юзер-агента браузера, айди и т.п., хэшируйте данные любым алгоритмом и кладите в сессию. Так при каждом обновлении хэш будет обновляться и если не совпадает с сессионным - не пускать на сайт, убивать сессию и т.п.

Comment: @InDevX юзер агент часто меняется после обновления браузера, айпи динамический, фингерпинт невозможно взять с техники apple + кто то использует расширение для изменения фингерпринта

Comment: Чтобы OAuth2 работал, не нужны гугл и т.д. Вам ничто не мешает поднять свой сервис аутентификации на сервере. Да и кто вам сказал, что токен у пользователя может быть только один? Посмотрите на мессенжеры. Вы можете залогиниться на нескольких устройствах одновременно

Comment: @ArchDemon сейчас буду изучать это. спасибо

Comment: вк спокойно входит по чужим куки, гугл тоже обходится даже с двухфакторной аутентификацией

Comment: @ArchDemon прочитал статью. а как это может помешать злоумышленнику с украденным токеном зайти в аккаунт ? проблема не решается

Comment: OAuth содержит 2 токена: один для доступа, другой - для обновления первого. Если украдут только первый, то через некоторое время он протухнет. В любом случае, ни одна технология вам не даёт 100% гарантии, что на той стороне "правильный" человек

Comment: @ArchDemon Проблема с обновлением в том, что если злоумышленник зайдет в аккаунт, то и обновляться токен будет у него до бесконечности (пока хозяин аккаунта не забьет тревогу).
Был вариант обновлять токен через ajax каждые несколько минут, но если злоумышленник выключит js, то токен не сможет обновиться

Comment: Токен можно обновить только с помощью токена обновления. Имея только токен входа, вы не сможете этого сделать